# Swift AVAudioPlayer doesn't play sound

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I want to play two sound files in my Swift app. "C1_bip.aif" and "false.aif".
They're both in the same folder in the project.

But when I start the app, the C1_bip sound is played and the false sound not and it prints Error to the Console.

The sound files are the same file type and I can play them both in the project explorer in Xcode.

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("C1_bip", ofType: "aif") {
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path), 
        fileTypeHint: "aif", error: nil)

        if let sound = audioPlayer {

            sound.prepareToPlay()
            sound.play()
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Error")
    }



   if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("false", ofType: "aif") {
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path), 
        fileTypeHint: "aif", error: nil)

        if let sound = audioPlayer {

            sound.prepareToPlay()
            sound.play()
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Error")
    }
```

Comment: this code is working fine for me.. so check your files you added into the project.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong. I put the file in the project folder and it doesn't work. But the one, which was there before works perfect...

Comment: with this code I can play both the files. so you should try to add false.aif file again

Comment: and remove that old file

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did in my test project:

```
    let musicPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bgmusic", ofType: "mp3")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: musicPath!)

    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    }catch _ {
        audioPlayer = nil
    }
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
```

And it did work well:)